# Scala respective "Cache-Money" implementation

Tags: scala, caching

Does anyone know a similar implementation of [Cache-Money](https://github.com/nkallen/cache-money) (Ruby) for scala?

Thank you!

Comment: "*Cacheing Library for ActiveRecord*" - you should first ask: "*Is there an ActiveRecord implementation in Scala*"?

Comment: check out oracle coherence - it may help... its java i think but will work with scala too.

Comment: I see your point Tomasz. I might've built my question wrong. What I want to know if there's any sort of cache wrapper library that easily integrates with memcache or relative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few project like [memcached.scala](https://github.com/jakedouglas/memcached.scala) or [scala-redis](https://github.com/acrosa/scala-redis)